# Acumatica - FieldUpdated - Enable / Disable another control when a checkbox is ticked / un-ticked

Tags: c#, acumatica

I have two custom fields, one is a tickbox, and the other is a text box, I wanted to change enabled/disable the text field on the screen when the tickbox value is changed, I added an event handler on the FieldUpdated event for the boolean checkbox control, and got the following code:

```
protected void CROpportunity_MyCheckbox_FieldUpdated(PXCache cache, PXFieldUpdatedEventArgs e)
{
  var row = (CROpportunity)e.Row;
}
```

Can I, and how to access other controls from this context?

I guess I need to enable CommitChanges on the checkbox which I did.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `RowSelected` event handler for enabling/disabling controls.
Here is an example of how you can do that:

```
protected virtual void CROpportunity_RowSelected(PXCache sender, PXRowSelectedEventArgs e,PXRowSelected baseMethod)
{
    baseMethod?.Invoke(sender, e);
    if(e.Row is CROpportunity row)
    {
        CROpportunityExt rowExt = PXCache<CROpportunity>.GetExtension<CROpportunityExt>(row);
        PXUIFieldAttribute.SetEnabled<CROpportunityExt.myTextField>(cache,row,rowExt.MyCheckbox==true)
    }
}
```

Comment: Is MyCheckbox the name of the control? or the name of the field?

Comment: I am getting: error CS0120: An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'PX.Data.PXCache.GetExtension<Extension>(object)'

Comment: Maybe because of the Standalone thing (opportunity has two weird types!!)

Comment: In two namespaces: PX.Objects.CR.Standalone and PX.Objects.CR